# What does `@` represent when dealing with Windows registry keys?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, regedit, syntax

What does `@` represent when dealing with Windows registry keys?

**Examples:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a broken import. When exporting to `.reg` files, `@` is the `(Default)` value:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Test]
@="Hello World"
```

[image: Regedit screenshot]

In your case, the `.reg` file might have contained this instead:

```
"@"="Hello World"
```

That makes it a regular value like any other. The meaning is up to the software reading this particular registry entry either way. That being said, I also have this value, so it probably comes with Windows by default.

In the neighboring keys, you can see that this value is supposed to go into the `(Default)` value. Whether this means anything is broken I cannot tell.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it was a fresh install. Windows 10 Enterprise. What about the data in the first screenshot; any idea about that one?

Comment: No. The Registry doesn’t define semantics.